# Trying to design a single op-amp oscillator

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, multisim

I am trying to build this single op-amp oscillator in Multisim but I keep getting this flat transient analysis. Is this what I am supposed to get? Am I using the wrong op-amp?[image: Multisim image of single op amp oscillator]

Comment: It should work. I can see nothing wrong about your circuit.

Comment: Try setting an initial voltage on the capacitor. something like 10V.

Comment: Are the triangles in the graph your time steps? If yes, you need to use much smaller steps.

Comment: Works in CrcuitLab if I use 10 uS steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s probably simulating the op-amp balanced on a knife-edge, a valid solution mathematically but unstable and a situation that won't occur and can’t persist in real life.

If you remove the initial condition calculation that usually gets rid of the issues .uic
or add a voltage step to nudge the circuit.

Comment: Added small voltage nudge and set the initial condition to zero and got this: https://imgur.com/a/3MXmRC2. Does that look about right?

Comment: It's working and it's about right, but  you might need to use smaller time steps to get accurate simulation around the switching points. A real op-amp model will show a bit more complexity around the switching points.